# XSLT: Parsing .Net Web.Config and attempting to add Node tree if it doesn't exist

Tags: xslt, configuration

I've been trying to use XSLT to parse through a the .net configuration file (web.config/app.config) and then perform different actions (like replacing attributes and creating new elements) and that's been going kinda well, but now I've been trying to recreate a node tree in the case that some or all of it does not already exist. Unfortunately I haven't gotten that to work yet.

I was wondering if someone could help me?

Example Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="setting1" value="true" />
    <add key="setting2" value="true" />
    <add key="setting3" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint name="endpointName1" address="http://endpoint1/endpoint1Service.svc" binding="endpointServiceBinding" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I would like to make it so that I can add in a new or other  node without disturbing any other  nodes and assuming it does not exist.

Client Certificate node (xpath? located below)

```
/configuration/system.serviceModel/behaviors/endpointBehaviors
       /behavior[@name=service1BehaviorName]/clientCredentials/clientCertificate
```

He's a simplified version of the problem if you get scared of the web.config :)

```
<Node1>
    <Node2>
        <Node3 name="1" value="value1" />
        <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
    </Node2>
</Node1>
```

I need information on how to do the following steps

1. Create Node2 if it does not exist
2. Either of the below statements

   - Create a new Node3 which has name="3"
   - Modify the contents of the Node3 with name="2"

I can write the code to add a new node, but I can't really figure out how to connect them

```
<!-- This should copy everything/be the the base rule -->
<xsl:template name="CopyAll" match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- This will check and see if node2 does not exist, and create it if it does not -->
<xsl:template name="rule_1" match="/Node1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="not(/Node1/Node2)">
            <Node2>
            <xsl:call-template name="rule_2"/> <!-- call rule 2 to create a node3 -->
            </Node2>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates /> <!-- Not sure why this is here, but it seems to need to be here in order to keep copying the xml file-->
</xsl:template>

<!-- Add node3 if it doesn't exist -->
<xsl:template name="rule_2" match="/Node1/Node2/">
    <xsl:if test="not(/Node1/Node2/Node3[@name=1/)>
        <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" />
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates /> <!-- Not sure why this is here, but it seems to need to be here in order to keep copying the xml file-->
 <xsl:template>

 <!-- Change the value of Node3 -->
 <xsl:template match="/Node1/Node2/node3[@name='1']">
<xsl:copy>
     <!-- Blanket statement for keeping all attributes -->
     <xsl:copy-of select ="@*" />
     <!-- Change the below attributes -->
     <xsl:attribute name="value">newValue</xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:apply-templates /><!-- Not sure why this is here, but it seems to need to be here in order to keep copying the xml file-->
</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Edit: 
I had another question, but since my original question was resolved, I went ahead an marked the first answer as the answer to my question. To be fair to Dimitre, his solution works as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a somewhat cleaner approach than your original attempt. Please bear in mind that XPath is case sensitive and `node3` is not the same as `Node3`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="treeToAddNF">
    <Node2>
      <Node3 name="1" value="">
        <Node4>
          <Node5/>
        </Node4>
      </Node3>
    </Node2>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="treeToAdd" select="exslt:node-set($treeToAddNF)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="Copy">
    <xsl:param name="contentsToAdd" select="/.." />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$contentsToAdd" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add Node2 to any Node1 that does not have a Node2 -->
  <xsl:template match="Node1[not(Node2)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="contentsToAdd" select="$treeToAdd/Node2" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add node3 if it doesn't exist -->
  <xsl:template match="Node2[not(Node3/@name = 1)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="contentsToAdd" select="$treeToAdd/Node2/*" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node3[@name = 1][not(Node4)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="contentsToAdd" select="$treeToAdd/Node2/Node3/*" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node3[@name = 1]/Node4[not(Node5)]">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy">
      <xsl:with-param name="contentsToAdd" select="$treeToAdd/Node2/Node3/Node4/*" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Node3[@name='1']/@value">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">newValue</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<Node1>

</Node1>
```

The result is:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue">
      <Node4>
        <Node5 />
      </Node4>
    </Node3>
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

When run on this input:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

The result is:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue">
      <Node4>
        <Node5 />
      </Node4>
    </Node3>
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

And when run on this input:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="value1" otherAttribute="7" />
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" otherAttribute="9"  />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

The result is:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" otherAttribute="7">
      <Node4>
        <Node5 />
      </Node4>
    </Node3>
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" otherAttribute="9" />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, Both or your solutions worked as you said they would. I had one last hurdle, I think, before I can go on and get this completed. In both of your solutions, you guys had hardcoded the whole tree if it didn't already exist. Looking at my web.config example from above, you'll notice that I could potentially have to create 5 to 6 nodes. Therefore, I am looking for a solution where I don't have to do that.

Comment: continued from above
Ex:
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3>
      <Node4 />
    </Node3>
  </Node2>
</Node1>

If I redid your current answers to solve the issue of adding "Node2","Node3", and "Node4," they would contain a way to add the full tree from "Node3" which contains the full tree of "Node4" along with a way to add "Node4" with the full "Node4" text. This would of course make it so that the exact same text for "Node4" would be in the XSLT twice. I'd prefer not to write the same stuff twice so that in the case that I rewrite it, I only have to change it in one location. Thanks

Comment: I've modified my answer above to avoid having duplicate copies of the parts to add in the XSLT. You'll note that the `value` attribute in the `treeToAddNF` variable is blank, but this is intentional. The template to handle that attribute takes care of giving it the right value and this also avoids duplication in the XSLT.

Comment: Just the answer that I was looking for. Thanks dude your help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a shorter solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Node1[not(Node2)]">
  <Node1>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <Node2>
        <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" />
      </Node2>
  </Node1>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Node3[@name='1']">
  <Node3 value="newValue">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='value')]|node()"/>
  </Node3>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Node2[not(Node3[@name='1'])]">
  <Node2>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" />
  </Node2>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When run on this XML document:**

```
<Node1>

</Node1>
```

**The result is**:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

**When run on this XML document:**

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

**The result is**:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" />
  </Node2>"
</Node1>
```

**And when run on this XML document**:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="value1" />
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

**The result is**:

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="newValue" />
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

**Finally, when run on this XML document:**

```
<Node1>
  <Node2>
    <Node3 name="1" value="value1" otherAttribute="7" />
    <Node3 name="2" value="value3" otherAttribute="9"  />
  </Node2>
</Node1>
```

**the result is**:

```
<Node1>
   <Node2>
      <Node3 value="newValue" name="1" otherAttribute="7"/>
      <Node3 name="2" value="value3" otherAttribute="9"/>
   </Node2>
</Node1>
```

Comment: Your solution is "much shorter" because it leaves out functionality. If the Node3 with name 1 has any attributes other than name and value or any child elements, they will be eliminated by your solution.

Comment: @JLRishe, It isn't clear that the OP needs this. I adjusted the solution for the new case pointed out by you, and the solution is still shorter :)